# Find all values greater or equal than a certain value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, excel-2010, excel-2013

Let's say I have the following table.

```
Team Score
AA   81
BB   67
CC   44
DD   1.5
JJ   279
LL   49
TT   201
GG   158
MM   32
HH   89
```

I want to get all teams that scored more than 80 in another table. I tried the Index + Match function as follows but it only gives me the smallest value greater than 80.

Here is the code:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(80,$B$2:$B$11,-1))
```

Although I put the values in the lookup_array argument in descending order, this function only gives me one answer: The smallest value greater than 80.

I am trying to do this without having to sort the array and with a huge database mind you. Thank you.

Comment: In all honesty, this is best done with VBA, not a set of formulas.

Comment: What would be the VBA code?

Answer (score 4):

Enter this formula to `D2` and press `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` to make it an array formula, then drag it down.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$11>=80,ROW($B$2:$B$11)),ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]

See [How to look up a value in a list and return multiple corresponding values](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/how-to-look-up-a-value-in-a-list-and-return-multiple-corresponding-values-HA001226038.aspx) for details.

Comment: Simplest and gives answer with array formula. +1

Answer (score 2):

How about using an AutoFilter? You're then quite flexible in filtering for values in column score.

Comment: This answer is essentially, google this term and do it yourself , It would be amazing if you could include some guidance

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use vba, in a third column you could have

```
=if(B2 > 80, A2, "")
```

and copy that formula down. You could even put this column of formulas in another tab and either delete the rows that have nothing in them manually or write code that will do that for you.

Comment: It would be best, but I am not sure this asker is after that solution. If it were me, and I guess you, @Quester, I would do something like this  `nextRow = 1 for i = 1 to 10 if cells(i,2) > 80 then cells(nextRow, 3)=cells(i,1) nextRow=nextRow+1 end if next i`

Answer (score 0):

Create a PivotTable (`Team` for ROWS, `Score` for Sigma VALUES, then filter the `Sum of Score` column for Number Filters, Greater Than..., and `80`  next to Show rows where: `is greater than` `*`, OK.

`*` or perhaps `is greater than or equal to`.