# Get values for all columns with value greater than 0

Tags: excel-formula, libreoffice-calc

I am using Libre Calc with a horizontal table like below

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | I | j |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | 0.1 |  |  | 0.7 | 2.3 | 5 |  |  |  |

And i would like to list values greater than 0 like below

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| b | 0.1 |
| e | 0.7 |
| f | 2.3 |
| g | 5 |

I have tried to use INDEX and MATCH with no success [How to use Index to find all values greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618463/how-to-use-index-to-find-all-values-greater-than)

=INDEX($R$4:$R$13,MATCH(1,($S$4:$S$13>0)*(COUNTIF($U$3:U3,$R$4:$R$13)=0),0))

I have also tried to create a separate Transpose of table and then run the above command with limited success.

Answer (score 0):

This task can be accomplished in several different ways.

The first option (which you tried) is with a long and obscure formula. More precisely, two formulas - the first will select the names of the columns that should be displayed, the second will pull the necessary values into the resulting table using the selected names (this can be an ordinary HLOOKUP())

(By the way, the formula that you tried to use is already morally outdated - now Excel has a [FILTER()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function, which, in combination with the TRASPOSE() function, will give the desired result much easier. Let's hope that Calc will soon also get functions like FILTER(), UNIQUE() and others)

Another way is to manually copy the original range, paste it into a new location using Paste Special (Ctrl+Shift+V) with the Transpose and Link options enabled, and then filter the resulting auxiliary range using the usual Standard filter, copying the filtering result to the specified location.

I prefer the third way - UDF, [User-defined function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-defined_function). The task is quite simple, the usual movement of data from place to place. Therefore, the algorithm is also simple and the macro code too:

```
Function TransposeAndFilter(aData As Variant) As Variant
Dim aResult As Variant 
Dim lB1 As Long, uB1 As Long 
Dim lB2 As Long, uB2 As Long 
Dim i As Long, j As Long, nextRow As Long 
    lB1 = LBound(aData, 1) : UB1 = UBound(aData, 1)
    lB2 = LBound(aData, 2) : UB2 = UBound(aData, 2)
    ReDim aResult(lB2 To uB2, lB1 To uB1)
    nextRow = lB2 - 1
    For i = lB2 To uB2
        If aData(uB1,i) > 0 Then 
            nextRow = nextRow + 1
            For j = lB1 To uB1
                    aResult(nextRow, j) = aData( j, i)
            Next j
        EndIf 
    Next i
    TransposeAndFilter = aResult
End Function
```

Write in a cell a formula like as `=TRANSPOSEANDFILTER(A1:I2)` and press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**